# Selenium and revolving containers

Tags: python, parsing, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There is a page with a table and a next button that refreshes the table. I am now able to extract the contents of the table but need to move on to the other rows using the next button. This is an ajax table of some sort with no href to refresh the page. Thus I am stuck. The page is  https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/6335/Stages/13796/PlayerStatistics/England-Premier-League-2016-2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do the following:

- start an endless loop
- click the next button - if it fails - exit the loop (this is your "break" condition)
- wait for invisibility of the table loading wrapper
- collect the players data

Sample implementation (using `selenium` only but you should probably involve `BeautifulSoup` for players data parsing - should be much faster):

```
from pprint import pprint

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException

root = "https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/6335/Stages/13796/PlayerStatistics/England-Premier-League-2016-2017"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(root)


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#statistics-table-summary .player-link")))

# get the first 10 players
players = [player.text for player in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#statistics-table-summary .player-link")]

while True:
    try:
        # click Next
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("next").click()
    except ElementNotVisibleException:
        break  # next is not present/visible

    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "statistics-table-summary-loading")))

    # collect the next 10 players
    players += [player.text for player in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#statistics-table-summary .player-link")]
    print(len(players))

pprint(players)
driver.close()
```

Note that as far as parsing goes, to improve performance, use the [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) to parse the relevant table only.

Comment: thank you my friend now I know the process to manipulate dynamic pages! Im very thankful! One small note: the while loop becomes endless and will add the names on the last page continuously so I added a condition to break after the count reaches 290 (284 players on list), and Im not sure why it does this because the element should not be visible to be clicked but this is no bother.. thank you friend!